# n-Party Garbled Circuit

Tags: multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

Yao introduced a famous notion of securely computing any function between 2 users using a concept of Garbling circuit. How can this idea be extended for n-party case? That is there are n-1 garblers and 1 evaluator.

How is the security of n-party garbled circuit defined? When is it useful?

Answer (score 2):

There is a very long line of work on multi-party garbled circuits -- too long to adequately describe in this answer. The first paper introducing multiparty garbling was:

- Beaver, Micali, Rogaway: [The Round Complexity of Secure Protocols](https://scholar.archive.org/work/7xxdxj6venfu7crulghyylwssa/access/wayback/http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/bmr90.pdf), STOC 1990.

Around the 2010s there was renewed interest in making the approach practical, with the following paper being an important turning point.

- Wang, Ranelucci, Katz: [Global-Scale Secure Multiparty Computation](https://obj.umiacs.umd.edu/papers_for_stories/wang_ACMCCS2017.pdf), ACM CCS 2017.

There have been several improvements since this WRK 2017 paper, but it remains the blueprint for the current state-of-the-art for multiparty garbling.

> How is the security of n-party garbled circuit defined?

It is generally not defined as a separate "garbling primitive" but just as a technique in an MPC protocol. We just use standard MPC security definitions.

> When is it useful?

When you want $n$-party MPC in constant rounds.